# AngularJS: goto previous url with refresh using $window

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie of AngularJS using version 1.6.4, What i am trying to do is redirect user on previous page with a complete refresh. Right now i am getting back but page is not refreshing. Any idea how can i do that with a single line code.

user-login.component.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var module = angular.module(__appName);

    function controller(authService, $window, $location, $document) {
        var model = this;

        model.$onInit = function () {
            //TODO:
        };

        model.login = function () {
            authService.login(model.email, model.password).then(function (response) {
                //$window.history.back();
                //$window.history.go(-1);
                //$window.location.href = '/';


                console.log("url:"+$document.referrer);
                //$document.referrer is showing undefined in console
                $location.replace($document.referrer);

            },
            function (response) {
                model.msg = response.error;
            });
        }
    }

    module.component("userLogin", {
        templateUrl: "components/user-login/user-login.template.html",
        bindings: {
            email: "<",
            password: "<"
        },
        controllerAs: "model",
        controller: ["authService", "$window", "$location", "$document" controller]
    });
}());
```

App.js:

```
"use strict";

//Global variables
var __apiRoot = "http://localhost:8000/api"; //No slash '/' at the end


var module = angular.module(__appName, [
    "ui.router",
    "angular-jwt"
]);

module.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, jwtOptionsProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');

    $stateProvider

        .state("app", {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/app",
            component: "appRouting"
        })

        .state("app.home", {
            url: "/home",
            component: "homeRouting"
        })

        .state("app.search", {
            url: "/search/:q",
            component: "searchRouting"
        });

    jwtOptionsProvider.config({
        tokenGetter: ['authService', function (authService) {
            return authService.getToken();
        }],
        whiteListedDomains: ['localhost']
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular-ui-router and have name of previous state then use :

```
$state.go('previousState', {}, { reload: true });
```

If you don't have the name of the previous state then you could use this piece of code it will run every time state change will occur.

```
$rootScope.previousState;
$rootScope.currentState;
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(ev, to, toParams, from,fromParams) {
  $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
  $rootScope.currentState = to.name;
  console.log('Previous state:'+$rootScope.previousState)
  console.log('Current state:'+$rootScope.currentState)
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell how to add this code as i am a newbie and troubling to do so, getting errors.

Comment: I have added app.js code of my file too in my post.

Answer (score 0):

you can refresh page by simply using native javascript. `window.location.reload()`

Comment: It will only reload current page. What I want is to reload previous page.

Comment: first redirect it into previous page then do page reload

Comment: use `location.replace()`. You can get the previous URL of where you came from using document.referrer.

`location.replace(document.referrer)`;

Answer (score 0):

use `$location.replace()`. You can get the previous URL of where you came from using $document.referrer. `$location.replace($document.referrer)`

Comment: $document.referrer is showing undefined in console. And my code get stuck there as i am not redirecting anywhere

Comment: I have updated the post to show you how am i doing $location.replace